# What is the most important for league play? Also what is CS?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [First thing to learn when beginning League of Legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17014/first-thing-to-learn-when-beginning-league-of-legends)

What is the most important thing you should do or practice if you want to become a league of legends, League player? As well what is CS exactly?

Comment: FYI, one question per post is preferred. Also, the subjective nature of the league question well likely illicit discussion answers and may also result in this question bring closed.

Answer (score 2):

The most important things in League of legends to learn are

1. CS and last hitting - you minion score is generally what wins games, not going for risky champion kills also last hittign will prevent you from pushing you lane and getting ganked.
2. Positioning - which way you should enter the river or come into a team fight, you dont' want to pin yourself or separate yourself from your team when possible
3. Map awareness and control - It is VERY important to watch your mini map and have good ward coverage. People will not always all a MIA when their lane comes to gank you. While they should have, your over extention or needless death is still on your own head for not being aware wheere the other team is. Make sure you always keep an eye on your mini map and ward in all key positions to prevent ganks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small addition about CS to the other answers (which pretty much covered everything else) because I did not see this explicitly mentioned in any of them:
CS = Creep Score = the amount of minions you landed the killing blow on and thus got gold from = A very significant part of your income (unless you are a support).

This is also why mastering last hitting (letting ally creeps bring enemy creeps down to within 1 of your normal attacks from death and ONLY THEN attacking it for the kill credit) with a given champion will give you a significant advantage in lane: This way you maximize your income without pushing the fight deeper into enemy territory (as you would if you just keep auto attacking), thus leaving yourself vulnerable to a gank. Do not be afraid to use a spell to get a last hit when 2 minions drop low at the same time, it is usually well worth the extra CS.

I should probably mention that there are also times you want to keep autoattacking or even using your spells to push the wave.

For example: if you KNOW your lane opponent went back to buy and the wave is near the enemy tower, AND you have sufficient map vision to be relatively safe from ganks, you should clear the minion wave so that your minions hit the enemy tower. This way you deny your opponent the exp and gold from those minions and do some damage to his tower AND have the wave then push back to your side once the tower clears the creeps. 
This can also be done if, (once again, ONLY if you have sufficient vision/position information on your enemies to be safe), your opponent's champion is miserable at last hitting at his tower (usually someone with bad autoattacks) and will lose a lot of CS to it and you have a champion that is good at clearing minion waves.

Just don't EVER overstay your welcome: feeding a minion wave to the enemy tower is NEVER worth a death.

Answer (score 0):

I would learn how to be map aware, jungle routes, and ward placement. Note that warding and map awareness are two different things. Map awareness means you know an opponent goes mia (missing in action). This is important due to they might be heading to gank another lane or be heading to a map objective such as a jungle buff, baron, or dragon. Jungle routes in my opinion are the second most important. Knowing them as a jungler can give you an exp, gold, and gank advantages over a novice jungler. On the other hand even if you aren't jungling for your team knowing where the enemy jungler is and what they are most likely to do. This knowledge can give you an advantage as you can prevent yourself from getting ganked or set up a counter gank for your team. The third most important is ward placement even if your not your teams support or jungler, you should usualy buy atleast one on your first back. Knowing where to put wards can give your team strong map control and prevent counter warding by putting them in obious place if the enemy team picks up an oracle elixer.

Answer (score 0):

**Practice and Champion Knowlege**: Before going into a game, know your champion and practice with bots, this way you will not feel yourself frustrated.

**Map awarness**: I have discovered that this is very hard to get, but when you manage to, you will enjoy more the game and wont get ganked that easy.

**And Patience**: A lot of this will help you to dont lose the cool and enjoy the game.