# What are the most important things for a newcomer to Leage of Legends learn?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [First thing to learn when beginning League of Legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17014/first-thing-to-learn-when-beginning-league-of-legends)

My friend recently started playing League of Legends, and I'm trying to help him learn how to play. What  should I be teaching them? Mechanics? Strategy/meta?

Answer (score 0):

In the early levels, team comps typically are quite varied, so the basic mechanics (last hitting/etc) would be more beneficial, since the overall meta isn't quite followed.