# How does the Co-op vs AI IP award system work?

Tags: pc, league-of-legends

I really like the new Co-op vs ai, match type introduced on LoL.

AFAIK, it awards a reasonable good amount of IP for winning once per day, just like your First Win of the Day double IP Boost.

I am asking this, because I have been awarded different amounts of IP with big gaps for winning, for instance:

-- I won with *6/2/5* and was awarded 192 IP pretty good

-- Won another match with *1/1/26* and was awarded just 45 IP

If anyone has idea on how are these awards given, let me know, because given the examples I have experienced, it tends to be biased towards having more kills, hence I could focus on doing so in order to get more IP.

Thanks

Comment: Are you playing against Beginner or Intermediate level AI? What is your summoner level?

Comment: Summoner lvl 30 and Intermediate level on both of the cases I mentioned

Comment: I was reading the faq but apparently it's down for maintenance now :S I guess it doesn't matter, a good answer will address all cases. You're at least doing the right mode for your level, although riot stated that normal games will likely serve you better for IP.

Comment: Correct Sir, I just like to do the daily Co-op vs All, in order to get some decent IP from there without any stress :p , however the big gaps on the rewards have me intrigued..

Comment: @camiloqp Just to be sure, you mean Co-op vs. *AI* (ai), correct?

Comment: Nunu Bot, [what have you done with yourself](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HN9CkKg7k0&t=37m17s)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I don't know of any specifics related to Coop (as compared to PvP), but I do know that Riot recently changed their formula.  If I understand the new formula correctly, there should be no difference between PvP and PvE IP/XP gains on a per game basis (obvious caps still apply).

Previously, the system was based around providing IP in comparison to the 20minute mark (also known as the surrender minimum time).  As you played towards that mark you gained more IP/XP and after that mark, these gains rapidly diminished.

To help explain this, let's take the following sample:

I play a PvP against Grace Note and she beats me 25 minutes in.  She gets about 115 IP (plus a  bonus) for winning and I get about 65 for losing.  Now, let's say we play again and again she wins, but this time it takes her 45 minutes to woop my butt.  I would get 72 IP for hanging in longer, but she would only get 100IP!

Obviously the goal here was to penalize longer wins and shorter losses.  Unfortunately, this encourages farming games, where teams agree to surrender at the 20 minute mark.  So Riot changed that formula to a new one.  Here's your TL;DR:

**IP/XP scales with time**

For those concerned about endless games, the formula is essentially linear up till the 55 minute mark.  Additionally, both Winners and Losers scale *up* with time (meaning you're no longer penalized for a long win).  There is also an extra flat bonus for playing the game which does not scale. Finally, they've also removed the bonus for non-leaver streaks (in preference to the new judgement system.

For more information on the new system you can [read here](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=6307048#post6307048).

Also, pictures!
[image]

---

Post Script

For those unaware there are also difficulty scaling modifiers for Coop vs AI

> These percentages represent how much of the standard reward is received:
>
> - Summoner level 1-9: Beginner: 100% Intermediate: 100%
> - Summoner level 11-19: Beginner: 75% Intermediate: 100%
> - Summoner level 20-29: Beginner: 50% Intermediate: 100%
> - Summoner level 30: Beginner: 25% Intermediate: 75%

Comment: Awesome information, thank you! Any idea on the percentage of games that fall beneath the threshold - i.e. 39 minutes according to your data? These graphs look very pro IP, but I bet the global IP gains are a lot less now, especially now you can surrender at 20 mins instead of the previous 25. Do these numbers also apply to 3v3 games?

Comment: @Dan I don't have global percentage numbers, but I do know that these numbers are designed to unify the 3v3, 5v5 and PvE systems into a single system, instead of using hacks (in the previous system 3v3 just got 30% less IP/XP).  Its also worth noting that you are still capped at the amount of IP/XP you can get from Custom/PvE games based on your level.

Answer (score 3):

The First-Win-Of-The-Day bonus applies to Co-op Vs. AI games, so your 195 IP reward likely came from your bonus (150 IP) meaning you would receive 45 IP without it. Compared to your second game, you earned the same amount of IP. You won't see big gaps apart from that bonus.

Beyond that, the [online faq](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=6864795) describes the reward system. Co-op vs. AI games incur a -25% reward penalty like custom games, and have an additional IP gain modifier applied based on summoner level and AI level:

**Summoner level 1-9**

- Beginner AI: 100%
- Intermediate AI: 100%

**Summoner level 11-19**

- Beginner AI: 75%
- Intermediate AI: 100%

**Summoner level 20-29**

- Beginner AI: 50%
- Intermediate AI: 100%

**Summoner level 30**

- Beginner AI: 25%
- Intermediate AI: 75%