# Is IP gained based at all on performance?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there any correlation between how well I do in game and how much IP I gain?  I already know that winning a game nets you more IP than losing a game.

But for example, if my team carries me to a win despite me going 0-10-0, will I get less IP than if I carry my team by going 15-0-0?

Comment: Doing 0-10-0 or 15-0-0 will only affect your elo on ranked games

Comment: @camiloqp - not even that, I don't think.

Comment: Slightly but it does +/- 3Elo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only performance metric that affects IP calculations is whether you WIN or LOSE.

The only other variable item that affects IP calculation is the length of the game. (More time spent = more IP earned)

So if you win fast, you'll get less IP than if you win after an hour of hardfought fighting. What's important to note is that *on average* the amount of IP gained / time spent is the same. (3 games at 20 minutes each should equal 1 game at 60 minutes each, for instance).

Comment: It's worth noting there is also a cap.  Past a certain point (55 minutes) playing longer does not give you more IP

Comment: @Tzenes - as of one of the recent patches, playing past 55 minutes continues to gain IP.

Comment: true the cap is now a historical footnote

Comment: You have a source for the win fast to IP paragraph or is it personal experience?

Comment: @joedragons It was based on how the game was 4 years ago. Dunno if they've tweaked IP gain in the time since.

Comment: @RavenDreamer thanks, I was hoping for a source for just that reason and continued my search and found one here if it helps anyone: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18485/how-does-the-co-op-vs-ai-ip-award-system-work