# What does SS stand for when an opponent is missing?

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

When someone from the opposing team is missing I have noticed people writing "SS bot/mid/top" to indicate to the rest of the team that they don't have visual on one or more of the people in there lain. But what dose the SS actually stand for?

Comment: Not an answer but related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-lol.

Comment: Very nice link, but as you mentioned not what I'm looking for

Comment: in dota1, ss used to refer to secret shop. "brb ss"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To directly answer your question, **'ss' is a shorter version of 'miss'**. In certain regions, they differentiate between this and "MIA", which is meant to refer to a specific opponent whose location is not known rather than a lane with missing people.

From [a forum post](http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=365442):

> SS (ss bot, ss bot 2, etc...)
>
> Miss, the enemy/enemies are missing from lanes. Normally only called during the laning phase of a game. The lane from where the enemy is missing can be (and should be) said after ss, and a number of enemies missing can be inserted after that; So "ss top 2" simply means that 2 enemy champions that were laning top are now missing, and your teams mid should be extra careful (as should you).
>
> MIA (mia noct, mia shaco, etc...)
>
> Missing in action, an enemy champion is missing in sense that your team does not know his location. For when you are going into a teamfight and only see 4 enemies ahead of you there is a good chance that Fiddlesticks is going to jump to you soon from his hiding place, for example.

On North American servers, people tend to use mia for both purposes:

- mia mid
- mia shaco

Comment: It also means 'Stay Safe' for the same reasons as you already noted. This is probably also a regional translation.

Answer (score 8):

The only explanation I've run across is that people outside of North America use SS as an abbreviation for "miSSing". And in N. America, MIA (Missing In Action) is the more common version.

Answer (score 2):

These answers are somewhat incorrect. 'SS' means 'Stay Safe' as opponent left lane he was on/ or is missing from that lane. This originated from DotA, as DotA players started playing LoL in it's early stages. (DotA is predecessor of LoL, and it is a mod for Warcraft III game )

Answer (score 0):

It does stand for a missing champion but I prefer the MIA usage.  SS could also potentially stand for summoner spells and I have seen people use that in game.

For example, "mid no ss" clearly means middle lane has no flash or ignite. I have seen people abbreviate this to "mid ss".  So, if someone calls this and their opposing laner is still in the lane it means they have just used their summoners, most likely.

Comment: This is true however for spells (especially flash) i and my team use no burn or no esc (escape). Same goes for no slow/ult/buff.

Answer (score 0):

SS = Missing or switching sides. It is not used with any other meaning (at least in EUW servers), though I have heard of some Americans using it for summoner spells. I wouldn't recommend that usage; for summoner spells it is more usefull to call the spell they burned, since ignite and flash are way diffrent things.

"Mid no flash"

"Galio burned r"

"ss Mid" - "care bot" (also it is better to not say things you can just ping. Just ping enemy missing (drag to the left and you're fine ;) (also ping danger in the direction they were heading))

Answer (score -1):

**ss** isn't also just a shorter version of "miss," it stands for (My lane is) **Switching Sides**.

Comment: +1 because you said the meaning (MISS) and because who downvote you, didn't post the reason, so ... making it 0 for a good view.

Comment: I threw a -1 because I've never seen someone call it switching sides and he offered no supporting evidence. I meant to comment but my domination game started.

Comment: downvoted for giving an incorrect answer.

Comment: That's just incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

I always thought of it meaning **single-sided**. Usually players tend to call **ss** when they notice in a dual players lane (usually top or bottom lane), that the one of the two opponents left that lane.

Of course, other interpretations as stated here are also valid.
When I started playing LoL back in the US servers, players relied more on calling **MIA**. Now in the EU servers, it seems that **ss** is more used.

Comment: They are not 'also' valid because your explanation is not valid. It's just what you thought, and you thought wrong.

Comment: @Sejanus Oh, I'm sorry! I didn't know you were the supreme judge! You downvoted because I based my answer on my opinion, but yet you show no proof of the contrary. Really constructive, keep it up!

Comment: You don't seem to understand how stackexchange works. This is not a discussion, this is Q/A and if you don't know the answer, you don't answer. Nobody has to prove you anything, you yourself admitted this was only your opinion. You just guessed what it means. Yes I will keep it up, calling on wrong answers and improving stackexchange quality.

Comment: I fully understand how it works. What I wonder is: if my answer is wrong for being based on an opinion, why didn't you bash every other answer here? AFAIK, there is no **official** definition of the term, and even the most voted answer here is based on a **forum post**. My answer is at most as arbitrarily wrong as your argument. More, the same forum post mentioned above is the one that contains the **switching sides** variation you bashed below as well.

Comment: Plus, on how SE works, the site states that "if you believe an answer to be wrong, consider commenting before downvoting". Guess you are the one who doesn't understand how SE works.