# What does mia stand for?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do those abbreviations mean in LoL?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-lol)

When someone from a lane is missing some people say mia,i know it means the same as ss but what does it stand for ?

Answer (score 3):

It stands for "Missing in action"

Comment: Correct.  The Europeans in particular also use "ss" to designate what many in North America refer to as "mia."  Please look at this thread for a more thorough explanation of what "ss" stands for: [http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56530/what-does-ss-stand-for-when-an-opponent-is-missing](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56530/what-does-ss-stand-for-when-an-opponent-is-missing)