# What exactly is QSS? Added new terms

Tags: league-of-legends

I was reading a response to one of my questions and I came across a term I have no idea what it means. QSS as well as like CS... really I could use someone to tell me what all the terms in league of legends mean. XD Total noob status with not knowing the terms. XD

going to add a few terms to this list.

IAS
Pilling
Sigils
DD
QQ
and last but not least PUG

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- QSS = the item Quick Silver Stash
- CS = your creep score, or minions killed
- IAS = Increased attack speed
- Pilling = Porting back to the base
- Sigil = Various things
- DD = Direct damage ability
- QQ = whine
- PUG = Pick up game

Answer (score 3):

QSS can be refered to the item Quicksilver Sash.

Answer (score 3):

QSS : Quick silver sash , wich gives you magic resist and a ''cleanse'' active.

CS: Creep score (How many minions someone has killed) .

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

CS refers to Creep score btw.  Not the subject question but was in OP's text.  In a MOBA like League of Legends, more gold means better items which tends to mean who is stronger, especially the longer the game goes.  The primary means of getting gold is to make the last hit that kills the minions that spawn in all 3 lanes or in the jungle neutral camps.  CS just refers to how many minions the player successfully got the gold from.

Answer (score 1):

QSS refers to the Quicksilver Sash, an item that cleanses all debuffs off your champion when activated. Useful in negating skills like ashe arrow and skarner ultimate. QSS is activated when you press the number corresponding to the item slot, therefore 1-6.

CS is you Creep Score, the number of minions where you have scored the killing blow (last hit) on the minion. This score consists of the lane minions, jungle minions, dragon, baron, and champion minions such as: heimerdinger cannons, yorick ghosts, malzahar voidlings.

CS is very important in League of Legends because 15cs=~1 kill.

Answer (score 0):

QSS refers to the Quicksilver Sash, an item that cleanses all debuffs off your champion when activated.

CS is you Creep Score, the number of minions where you have scored the killing blow (last hit) on the minion.

As an aside, a list of all terminology used in LoL, including acronyms, can be found at http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_terminology

Comment: oh I will look at it XD I just added some other terms to. *doe*

Answer (score 0):

QSS means Quicksilver Sash and CS means Creep Score. However, I cannot explain any of the other terms except QQ. QQ is referred as crying which is usually used in an offensive way. I hope this helped you

Answer (score 0):

IAS= Uhm... No idea.
Pilling= Going back to your base by pressing B or the recall button.
Sigils= Red/blue buffs or buffs in Dominion. Could also mean Leblanc's Q.
DD= Direct Damge
QQ= It's a crying emote face.
and last but not least PUG= "Pick-Up Group" Meaning randoms.

:) Good luck and have fun!