# What does CS mean and how do you increase it the best you can?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do those abbreviations mean in LoL?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-lol)

What does "CS" mean?
& How do I get a lot of it?

Answer (score 2):

"CS" is shorthand for "Creep Score", and is the number of creeps (neutral jungle creeps or the enemy's creeps) that you have scored the last hit on and obtained gold from.

If you are laning, the number one way to improve your CS is to simply work on it on your own in custom games. Focus solely on letting minions wail away on each other until they are one auto-attack away from death, *then* attack. If you're just starting out, you want to aim for 6-8 CS per minute; better players want to aim for about 10 per minute.

Answer (score 0):

CS is Creep Score, it is the amount of minions you've killed (gotten the last hit on).  YOu can get a lot of it by last hitting the minions in your lane.