# What does "CC" mean?

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do those abbreviations mean in LoL?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-lol)

People always say this in my games, "Their team has more CC than us." or "We don't have enough CC." What does it mean in League of Legends?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz CC is not listed in the possible duplicate

Comment: @Blem It is now. We don't need two of these.

Answer (score 4):

It stands for crowd control, which means ablilites that affect a champion's status (stuns, snares, silences, fears) or their ability to move (slows, snares, stuns, fears).