# What does GP10S mean?

Tags: league-of-legends

What does GP10S mean in League of Legends chat? I've seen a lot of people use it but I don't understand what it means. Does the 10 have an significance?

Comment: Question already answered [What do those abbreviations mean in League of Legends?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-league-of-legends)

Answer (score 13):

Gold / 10 sec.
For example, Philosopher's Stone will give you 5 GP10.

So every 10 seconds you will make 5 extra gold
Or every minute you will make 30 extra gold
Or every 10 minutes you will make 300 extra gold

Comment: @GP10 remember to mark the answer as accepted if it satisfied you, you can do so by clicking the check icon to the left of the question.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but he just displayed exactly what is completley wrong with the LoL community.

Comment: @Emerica What?  By asking a question and trying to get better informed?  That seems like a good behavior to me.

Comment: @Jeff: please take a look at the [first version of this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/114334/1) (also one of the very first entries on "GP10S" by Google is an entire Wiki page dedicated to this topic).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Hahaha, I see.  Nice.

Comment: @Jeff Also the comment on the answer which may have been deleted.