# How do you explain ganking, carrying, farming, etc. to a newcomer?

Tags: dota-2, terminology

These terms can only be fully learned after hours of practice, but to give a beginner a feel of these terms when his or her team talks about these, how would you explain these terms in context of DotA 2?

Comment: While this is about Dota2 and not LoL, they almost use the same words for the same actions. Therefore, I think that this question will answer most of your questions: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-league-of-legends

Comment: Looking at the other question, the terms used in this question are not covered at all in the other ones. Still feel like a duplicate but the other question doesn't cover all the terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Farm**: Kill enemy lane creeps and neutral creeps to amass gold and experience.
- **Gank**: Invest time in attempting to kill an opponent to set back his progress.
- **Carry**: A type of hero who spends more time farming than doing other tasks because he is able to accomplish more in lategame with
  items than other heroes.

Answer (score 0):

You can explain these terms by using simple words:

**Ganking** - Ganging up on someone.

**Carrying** - To do so well that the team's victory is based on this player's actions.  Basically like being *carried on someone's back*.

**Farming** - Killing an easy target for resources, like a "fish farm".

Comment: Don't you think the definition of carry is a bit too general and abstract?

Comment: What's too general and abstract about it?

Comment: I think its not downvote worthy but in your description it sounds as if the carrying player is much more skilled and the others are just bad. ^^