# How much should we spend on wards?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips for warding in League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/tips-for-warding-in-league-of-legends)

I have recently started playing support. So far I am doing pretty well supporting but I have trouble with one thing. How much gold should I split between buying wards and buying items. I start out with 2 wards. Then afterwards I buy like 3 wards at each recall. But my teammates complained and said I should be buying more wards than that. So of course I started buying at least 5 wards each time. But then they complained that I didn't have any good support items and that I should work on that. Well come on guys, I only have so much gold. And yes I do build the gold per 5 items. Typically philosophers stone first.

So my question is, as the support on a team, how much wards should i buy at each recall, or maybe what percentage of my gold should i dedicate to wards?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't really a matter of how much you spend, your main role is to make sure key points are always warded at certain times.

In lane, you want to ward drake at around level 5. This is when the junglers will be fighting over control of the dragon. It is hard to say how much exactly, but probably  50-75% of my gold goes on wards when I play support.

I **always** prioritise wards over items. No exception. If you have spare wards in your inventory and the map is appropriately warded then spend spare gold on an item. Try to get a Philosophers stone as early as you can, but you  may not be able to afford it until your second recall. That is fine. Warding the brush in lane gives your carry a big advantage, don't put off buying extra wards for them and holding off those items for a bit longer. If your carry has an advantage over the enemies, then your entire team is at an advantage.

Try to get the gp/10 quints on too. They help a lot, plus they are cheap (1k IP each)

I try to buy a purple ward for drake, its more expensive, but it counters better. (Actually this should be the junglers job, but make sure you do it if they don't)

My personal item priorities are:

1. Wards
2. Philo Stone
3. Boots (1)
4. Kage's lucky pick
5. HoG
6. Boots (2)
7. Aegis
8. Shurelya's Reverie

The game should never really last past an Aegis.

Comment: +1 for gp/10 Quints but -1 for HoG at the bottom of the list ;p I usually get it before t2 boots

Comment: Haha fair enough. I tend to do fine with just 2 gp/5 items and lots of assists. I'll edit the post though because it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific amount you should ever be spending on wards. LoL is a dynamic game and thus you have to play it like one. If you have an enemy jungler make sure you are warding common paths, if not wards are slighly less important as long as the team is calling MIAs. Ward the dragon and late game ward baron. Don't get to hung up on the ward aspect of support, use your clairvoyance frequently and intelligently. Focus more on the physical support, healing, defending and keeping your team alive. If your team is complaing you aren't warding enough and you are warding as frequently as you say then they are clearly babied. Watch your map if you're concerned with MIAs. Your gold could be used much more effitiently boosting your healing and defensive effects.