# Where are the best places to put a ward and could visible wards be better over oracle elixers?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips for warding in League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/tips-for-warding-in-league-of-legends)

Where do you usually place wards and why are some locations better then others?
Visible Wards or elixers?

Answer (score 3):

There are many different scenarios where the different items would become better than others. Just starting off with sight wards just to prepare yourself for any movement or ganks. Vision wards would be good for common ward locations to clear the ward and give you vision over it. Such as warding dragon to gain the sight and check for their ward there (which most people do ward). Oracles would be or hunting invisible people such a Twitch, Akali(shroud), Evelynn, and others. It would also be good if you are trying to gank and people keep backing off since it's warded. I would only advise if you are doing really well early game to buy an Oracle's just to kill their wards. Here is a link that would go more in depth of what I've just said (well I think so, I've never read the guide).
http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/warding-helper-more-than-your-eyes-can-see-54337

Answer (score 2):

Some of the most common ward locations include (in rough priority order):

- Exits from the enemy jungle to the river - to see an enemy jungler coming your way for ganks
- In the river near Dragon or Baron - to keep an eye out for the enemy team killing those monsters
- In the river brush closest to the top/bottom lane - to guard against ganks coming up the river
- In the "tribrush" in bottom (blue) and top (purple) lanes - again, to protect against ganks
- In the middle river brush - to guard mid lane from ganks
- In the bottom/top lane brush - if the enemy laners are using it heavily to hide and poke you

There are many other spots that can be perfectly worthwhile for wards, but these are some of the most common.  My rule of thumb is: look and see where enemies could approach you unseen.  If there's an obvious path they can take to surprise and kill you, you should probably get a ward up there to give you advance warning.

Vision Wards can be very useful in a few situations:

- When warding an area you know the enemy team may have warded, like Dragon - you can gain vision there and also kill off their vision at the same time
- When the enemy team is relying heavily on stealth - you can drop one where you're last hitting to guard against Twitch or drop one in a teamfight to keep Akali from getting away.

Vision Wards are cheaper than Oracle Elixir, and if you die your investment isn't lost, although obviously you can only use them once.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.lolpro.com/guides/game-play/172-game-play-guide-controlling-buffs/controlling-buffs

http://www.lolpro.com/guides/game-play/174-game-play-guide-baron-dragon-control

These may be able to help you out. Having map control and securing objectives is a huge importance and these two guides may help you on where to ward.

Answer (score 1):

Hey take a look at this link: [Tips for warding in League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/tips-for-warding-in-league-of-legends)

and now. A look at our [search](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=ward)

=)