# Warding of the map

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips for warding in League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/tips-for-warding-in-league-of-legends)

The live stream has been bringing my attention to something: the importance of wards. However, your build is also very important. I was wondering, what is the most effective placement pattern of wards to get maximum vision for limited cost? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this map is saying is Pink ward dragon and baron to be able to keep them clear of enemy wards, sight ward your tri-brush top and bottom, the entrances to both buffs, as well as the river for ganks from other lanes. And if you can afford it, ward the brush in bot lane, as it helps keep their support from zoning your AD carry from farming, as well as stops lane ganks from your opponents jungle.

[image]