# Ward placing on bottomlane

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips for warding in League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/tips-for-warding-in-league-of-legends)

Should the purple-bottomelane rather ward the ramp into the enemy jungle or ward their own ramp into their jungle to protect bluebuff and get vision over dragon?
Because by warding dragon/blueramp they wont have any vision over a tribush ganks.

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning I would ward the bush in the river, and when the enemy can take dragon you need atleast a ward there, and probably another in the tri-bush area.