# New season 4 map image

Tags: league-of-legends

Do someone know of a way to get a full image of the new (pre-)season 4 map?

I'd really like to update my [guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/how-do-i-ward-properly-in-league-of-legends/34507#34507) with new design and new tips for the new gameplay.

The map has to be detailed enough, not just an approximate drawing or look-alike.

Edit: I found out there used to be a RAF manager that would allow to access in game resources, but it seems to be no longer available.

Comment: Unless the map's actually been released for play, this isn't something we can help with.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to extract it from the files maybe.

Comment: A new map got released yesterday with the new patch - while it may yet change more for season 4, I (and likely @M'vy) would like an image of the new map. Or is @M'vy only asking for the Season 4 map?

Comment: @Bob2Chiv the map isn't gonna change that much, or by small details. I just need resources to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Old Summoner's Rift

[image: Old Summoner's Rift]

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/1kt9ae/summoners_rift_new_map/

Updated for new Summoner's Rift

[image: Season 5 map]

Comment: I don't think this is the season 4 map..

Comment: @3ventic It isn't, you have to look closely and you'll see the brush sizes are the old style. Also top only has 2 brush in this image as well.

Comment: Ah you're right, it must be a pre lawnmowing version. I saw the new minion camp so i assumed. My bad