# For beginners, what champion would be suggested to start off with?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who is the best hero for a beginner?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4909/who-is-the-best-hero-for-a-beginner)

I've just started League of Legends recently, as a low level, I was curious what champions are good for beginners? I'm sure there are champions that have higher level skill caps but I'm still unsure of which champion to start off with then eventually branch off. The only champion I have tried and continued to play recently is Ryze and I have not been doing so hot. So, all in all, for beginners, which champion(s) would be best to help a beginner to branch off from?

Answer (score 0):

Ashe is pretty easy to get used to and to play. She's simple.

Answer (score 0):

Annie is a very easy champ to play who will also teach you some good habits for higher level play (for example, last hitting, a very important mechanic).

Answer (score 0):

Ashe was my first champ I've played. I've tried other champs too, however, Ashe, in my opinion, requires the lowest skill level.

Answer (score 0):

The best champions to get are the champions that are worth the least. For two reasons: one you're not spending your money on a champion you may not like, and two they are some of the easier champions to play. you can check out their difficulty by clicking on the champion in the store and it will be located with its other stats (health, attack, spells). Also heroes with the tag "recommended" are usually easy to use as well.

Some examples of heroes you should get are: Ashe, Annie, Master Yi, Soraka. Once you get a better handle on the game and champions I would suggest considering more expensive heroes.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do really. Tryn if you want to be that guy to run up get into their face own them, Ashe if you want to be a late game carry (needs to get fed/farmed to do a good bit of damage)

Answer (score 0):

Annie is a good beginner AP champion since she has a lot of damage her passive makes her 4th spell stun and she isn't too hard to learn.

Ashe would be my recommend for a AD hero which has a lot of cc and a good ultimate which stuns for 4 seconds and slows all around the person who it hits though she isn't as easy as Annie to learn.

Tryndamere is a recommended hero since he has a spin that you can use to get away or get close up, a slow to stop people from running away and a heal for when you lose health.
also his ultimate will keep you alive for 5 seconds beyond your health pool if used before your health reaches 0.

This makes Tryndamere easier to get away with doing mistakes.

This isn't the best answer but it's my opinion and I think those heroes would be best to use till your more used to playing this game.

Answer (score 0):

Well from some experiance  you start with some  free champions . When i learned my friends to play LOL and they were wondering what champion to play .. But the best think i sayed to them that ,,Guys make some games with the free champions  and then you can make a choice what class ,,role'' is best for you  i myself am playing all of them  but for few days i stopped at AP (Ability Power ) champions  ,,casters''   if you like my idea try it   try  the free champion  find a champion there play it for 4-5 days and if you like it that much get it with IP points : ) Hope i was usefull somehow :) and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Ashe. She helps you learn last hitting, mana control (volley and ultimate), map awareness (e), aiming (r), and staying alive (she is super squishy.) It's as if she was built for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

if you play tutoral, everybodys first champ was ashe, they wanted you to have a easy champ to play, and ashe is probibly easyest to understand, and good for non close combat for beginners who turret dive.