# When do you start buying wards, and when do you stop?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just recently started playing ranked, and a lot of people keep on telling me to buy wards. What's a good time to start buying wards, and at what point of the game do you stop buying wards?

Comment: You start as soon as you can afford them, and stop when you no longer have space in your inventory.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your lane and role. If you are support you want to start with at least 2 wards and a fairy charm. As every other role. I grab a ward after my first buy because you want to secure your lane from ganks.

As for when to stop. You should never stop. I like to make sure I always have at least one ward on me in case my support might not have one. Knowing where your opponent is wins games a large portion of the time. So do not stop warding.

Answer (score 2):

You should ALWAYS buy 1 or 2 wards until you are finished with your gear.

---

BUT it's not always possible, so here we go:

Let's split by lane:

**JUNGLE**

> Buy 1 or 2 when you get in the base after your first walk in the
>   jungle. keep trying 1 or 2 every time you get back in the base

**TOP**

> Try buy 1 at the beginner of the match or as soon as possible, recall
>   and shop 1 or 2. Keep at least the river warded.

**MID**

> Try buy 1 at the beginner of the match or as soon as possible, recall
>   and shop 1 or 2. Combine with your jungle, so he can ward one part of the river and you do the other.

**BOTTOM**

> If you are with a support, you can focus more in your gear. But you need buy some too. So when you have a spare of money, buy a couple or it and help warding dragon and river.

Here a great link for [warding map](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/tips-for-warding-in-league-of-legends)

Answer (score 0):

If you play support you usually start out with wards, pots, and faerie charm. Other than that you want to buy them anytime you have alittle extra gold, ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You tend to be wards to help the team, especially useful early game, (laning phase)

wards tend to lose some of its usefulness late game.

Early on, warding for baron is useless as it didnt spawn. Later on when champions are higher level, there is a chance for people to baron thus it should be warded.

Warding is basically for vision, if you have won every lane, there isnt a point to ward

Answer (score 0):

If your support: Start out by buying at least 1 wards to prevent early gank at bot.
If your Top/Mid: Wait till you go back first time and just buy a ward once you feel like it, unless you perma push I would recommend just having 1 ward up all the time and stick to that side of the lane.

If your jungler: buy wards at around 5-10 minutes and keep doing it, to prevent getting counterjungled a lot.

Mid/late game when the lane phases is gone, I would recommend just letting your support pick up wards/oracle. But of course, if you got bag space and a bit of gold left, then buy a ward just to help your team.

Answer (score 0):

Wards are good at all points in the game. Normally a support player will start with 3 wards. If you are in the mid or top lane I will usually buy a ward or two the first time i go back and continue to buy wards throughout the game. The support player will buy the majority of the wards so dont go wards crazy. Warding the river or the enemy jungle will help prevent the enemy jungler from ganking and help your jungler counter jungle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the support, you buy them at level one, and you don't stop until one of the nexus' is dead. If you are another role, you buy them on your first return to base, and don't stop until you have full build. Map awareness wins games.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should keep buying wards to try and have a constant map control, and if the the opposing team buys a oracle, then you kill that target and start all over again.

This is just in a perfect world thou, every match is different and you have to adapt to the situation when it's needed...

Answer (score 0):

It is best to begin buying them as soon as the jungler can begin ganking successfully. If it is an early ganking jungler, you might want to start with wards although usually this is only done by supports in bot lane. For mid and top you want to start picking them up after your first trip back. Never stop buying them.

Answer (score 0):

Buy wards immediately when the game starts but you don't want to place them before the general level in the game is 3 or 4 because most jungler's can't do a good gank until those levels. You almost never want to stop warding in fact you actually want to buy more and extend your vision of the map. You only stop when you reach the very late game when not much is happening but team fights as long as u have baron and dragon warded.